# How to compare if multi-class outputs are different?

Tags: classification, multi-class, differences

I am testing different multi-class (16 classes) classification models (ANN, DNN, DL, and so on) and the overall accuracy varies from 0.75 to 0.92. Despite that 0.92 is greater than 0.75, is there a way to compare the outputs statistically? I do not know if cotigency tables are the way to go, since I want to compare the output with to the original label as well. For instance, in the following example:

| Observed value | Prediction 1 | Prediction 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | C |
| B | B | B |
| A | A | C |
| B | B | B |
| B | B | B |
| C | C | C |
| B | C | C |
| C | C | A |

How can I stablish if *Prediction 1* is different than *Observed value*, or *Prediction 2* different than *Observed value* or *Prediction 1*? What is the suitable statistical test for this purpose?

Comment: I answered a similar post and recommended not performing a lot statistical analyses on classifier results here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637282/what-is-the-hypothesis-test-ive-used-or-what-should-i-change-to-fit-a-common/637292#637292

Comment: Thank you, it was very enlightening